big circle and draw three small protrusions or depressions
I want to draw a big circle and draw three small protrusions or depressions inward or outward at the positions of 90, 210, and 330 degrees respectively. The circumference of the circle should be broken at the protrusions or depressions and naturally connected with the protrusions or depressions, without drawing the protrusions or depressions directly on the circumference. Is there any way to accomplish this?
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\R{3} 

\foreach \i in {30,150,270} {
    \path (\i:\R) coordinate (P\i); 

    \path (\i:\R) coordinate (T\i);  
    \draw[thick]
      (P\i) .. controls +(\i+25:\R*0.5) and +(\i-25:\R*0.5) .. (T\i)
      .. controls +(\i-25:\R*0.5) and +(\i+25:\R*0.5) .. (P\i); 
}

\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\R cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}






I've tried to correct your markup. could you make sure I've got all the stray backslashes out? you don't need to escape square brackets (or anything) when marking up as code. if you do, they appear literally in the source code.

@cfr: I do not think it is something OP does on purpose - see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319353/adding-a-link-to-a-code-with-brackets-escapes-it-automatically It is the interface when used incorrectly somehow.

@hpekristiansen ah, now it makes sense - thanks. quite a confusing bug.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gap}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\loose}{1}
\draw[fill=pink, looseness=\loose] (30-\gap:\r) foreach \a in {30,150,270} { 
to[out=\a-\gap+90, in=\a+90] (\a:\R) to[out=\a-90, in=\a+\gap-90] (\a+\gap:\r)
arc[start angle=\a+\gap, end angle=\a+120-\gap, radius=\r]} --cycle;
\fill (45:1.2) circle[radius=0.4] (135:1.2) circle[radius=0.4];
\fill[white, xshift=2] (45:1.2) circle[radius=0.2] (135:1.2) circle[radius=0.2];
\draw[line width=5pt, line cap=round] (-130:1.8) arc[start angle=-130, end angle=-50, radius=1.8];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Different parameters:






this made me smile :-).

Thank you very much for your answer!@hpekristiansen
